# boundares - if object is past, delete object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, boundary

I have a code below that has rocks moving from left to right, I would like to create a boundary for them that they can only move a certain way in on the stage, once they get past this point they delete. I have tried to write this up under the Wrap Rocks and Delete Rocks section, but it's not working and it's not giving me any errors. Does anyone have any thoughts that might help me?

let me know if you need to see more code:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class SpaceRocks_v002 extends MovieClip {
    static const shipRotationSpeed:Number = .1;
    static const rockSpeedStart:Number = .03;
    static const rockSpeedIncrease:Number = .02;
    static const missileSpeed:Number = .2;
    static const thrustPower:Number = .15;
    static const shipRadius:Number = 20;
    static const startingShips:uint = 3;

    // game objects
    private var ship:Ship;
    private var rocks:Array;
    private var missiles:Array;

    // animation timer
    private var lastTime:uint;

    // arrow keys
    private var rightArrow:Boolean = false;
    private var leftArrow:Boolean = false;
    private var upArrow:Boolean = false;

    // ship velocity
    private var shipMoveX:Number;
    private var shipMoveY:Number;

    // timers
    private var delayTimer:Timer;
    private var shieldTimer:Timer;

    // game mode
    private var gameMode:String;
    private var shieldOn:Boolean;

    // ships and shields
    private var shipsLeft:uint;
    private var shieldsLeft:uint;
    private var shipIcons:Array;
    private var shieldIcons:Array;
    private var scoreDisplay:TextField;

    // score and level
    private var gameScore:Number;
    private var gameLevel:uint;

    // sprites
    private var gameObjects:Sprite;
    private var scoreObjects:Sprite;


    // start the game
    public function startSpaceRocks_v002():void {
        // set up sprites
        gameObjects = new Sprite();
        addChild(gameObjects);
        scoreObjects = new Sprite();
        addChild(scoreObjects);

        // reset score objects
        gameLevel = 1;
        shipsLeft = startingShips;
        gameScore = 0;
        createShipIcons();
        createScoreDisplay();

        // set up listeners
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveGameObjects);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpFunction);

        // start 
        gameMode = "delay";
        shieldOn = false;
        missiles = new Array();
        nextRockWave(null);
        newShip(null);
    }


    // SCORE OBJECTS

    // draw number of ships left
    public function createShipIcons() {
        shipIcons = new Array();
        for(var i:uint=0;i<shipsLeft;i++) {
            var newShip:ShipIcon = new ShipIcon();
            newShip.x = 20+i*15;
            newShip.y = 375;
            scoreObjects.addChild(newShip);
            shipIcons.push(newShip);
        }
    }

    // draw number of shields left
    public function createShieldIcons() {
        shieldIcons = new Array();
        for(var i:uint=0;i<shieldsLeft;i++) {
            var newShield:ShieldIcon = new ShieldIcon();
            newShield.x = 530-i*15;
            newShield.y = 375;
            scoreObjects.addChild(newShield);
            shieldIcons.push(newShield);
        }
    }

    // put the numerical score at the upper right
    public function createScoreDisplay() {
        scoreDisplay = new TextField();
        scoreDisplay.x = 480;
        scoreDisplay.y = 100;
        scoreDisplay.width = 20;
        scoreDisplay.selectable = false;
        var scoreDisplayFormat = new TextFormat();
        scoreDisplayFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;
        scoreDisplayFormat.font = "Arial";
        scoreDisplayFormat.align = "right";
        scoreDisplayFormat.size = 15;
        scoreDisplay.defaultTextFormat = scoreDisplayFormat;
        scoreObjects.addChild(scoreDisplay);
        updateScore();
    }

    // new score to show
    public function updateScore() {
        scoreDisplay.text = String(gameScore);
    }

    // remove a ship icon
    public function removeShipIcon() {
        scoreObjects.removeChild(shipIcons.pop());
    }

    // remove a shield icon
    public function removeShieldIcon() {
        scoreObjects.removeChild(shieldIcons.pop());
    }

    // remove the rest of the ship icons
    public function removeAllShipIcons() {
        while (shipIcons.length > 0) {
            removeShipIcon();
        }
    }

    // remove the rest of the shield icons
    public function removeAllShieldIcons() {
        while (shieldIcons.length > 0) {
            removeShieldIcon();
        }
    }



    // SHIP CREATION AND MOVEMENT

    // create a new ship
    public function newShip(event:TimerEvent) {
        // if ship exists, remove it
        if (ship != null) {
            gameObjects.removeChild(ship);
            ship = null;
        }

        // no more ships
        if (shipsLeft < 1) {
            endGame();
            return;
        }

        // create, position, and add new ship
        ship = new Ship();
        ship.gotoAndStop(1);
        ship.x = 400;
        ship.y = 350;
        ship.rotation = -180;
        ship.shield.visible = false;
        gameObjects.addChild(ship);

        // set up ship properties
        shipMoveX = 0.0;
        shipMoveY = 0.0;
        gameMode = "play";

        // set up shields
        shieldsLeft = 3;
        createShieldIcons();

        // all lives but the first start with a free shield
        if (shipsLeft != startingShips) {
            startShield(true);
        }
    }

    // register key presses
    public function keyDownFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
                leftArrow = true;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                rightArrow = true;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 32) { // space
                newMissile();
        } else if (event.keyCode == 90) { // z
                startShield(false);
        }
    }

    // register key ups
    public function keyUpFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode == 38) {
            leftArrow = false;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
            rightArrow = false;
        }
    }

    // animate ship
    public function moveShip(timeDiff:uint) {

        // rotate and thrust
        if (leftArrow) {
            ship.y -= 2;
        } else if (rightArrow) {
            ship.y+= 2;
            }

        // move
        ship.x += shipMoveX;
        ship.y += shipMoveY;

        // check boundaries
        if (ship.y < 65) ship.y = 65;
        if (ship.y > 380) ship.y = 380;

    }

    // remove ship
    public function shipHit() {
        gameMode = "delay";
        ship.gotoAndPlay("explode");
        removeAllShieldIcons();
        delayTimer = new Timer(2000,1);
        delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newShip);
        delayTimer.start();
        removeShipIcon();
        shipsLeft--;
    }

    // turn on shield for 3 seconds
    public function startShield(freeShield:Boolean) {
        if (shieldsLeft < 1) return; // no shields left
        if (shieldOn) return; // shield already on

        // turn on shield and set timer to turn off
        ship.shield.visible = true;
        shieldTimer = new Timer(3000,1);
        shieldTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,endShield);
        shieldTimer.start();

        // update shields remaining
        if (!freeShield) {
            removeShieldIcon();
            shieldsLeft--;
        }
        shieldOn = true;
    }

    // turn off shield
    public function endShield(event:TimerEvent) {
        ship.shield.visible = false;
        shieldOn = false;
    }


    // ROCKS        

    // create a single rock of a specific size
    public function newRock(x,y:int, rockType:String) {

        // create appropriate new class
        var newRock:MovieClip;
        var rockRadius:Number;
        if (rockType == "Big") {
            newRock = new Rock_Big();
            rockRadius = 35;
        } else if (rockType == "Medium") {
            newRock = new Rock_Medium();
            rockRadius = 20;
        } else if (rockType == "Small") {
            newRock = new Rock_Small();
            rockRadius = 10;
        }


        // choose a random look
        newRock.gotoAndStop(Math.ceil(Math.random()*3+1));

        // set start position
        newRock.x = Math.random()*0;
        newRock.y = Math.random()*280+80;

        // set random movement and rotation

        var dx:Number = Math.random()*3;  
        var dy:Number = Math.random()*2;

        // add to stage and to rocks list
        gameObjects.addChild(newRock);
        rocks.push({rock:newRock, dx:dx, dy:dy, rockType:rockType, rockRadius: rockRadius});
    }

    // create four rocks
    public function nextRockWave(event:TimerEvent) {
        rocks = new Array();
        newRock(100,1,"Big");
        newRock(200,1,"Big");
        newRock(450,1,"Big");
        newRock(350,1,"Big");

        gameMode = "play";
    }

    // animate all rocks
    public function moveRocks(timeDiff:uint) {
        for(var i:int=rocks.length-1;i>=0;i--) {

            // move the rocks
            var rockSpeed:Number = rockSpeedStart + rockSpeedIncrease*gameLevel;
            rocks[i].rock.x += rocks[i].dx*timeDiff*rockSpeed;
            rocks[i].rock.y += rocks[i].dy*rockSpeed;


            // wrap rocks
    if ((rocks[i].rock.x > 0) && (x <-50)) {
            deleteRocks();
        }
            else if ((rocks[i].rock.x < 0) && (x > 50)) {
            deleteRocks();          
        }


        }
    }

    public function rockHit(rockNum:uint) {
        // create two smaller rocks
        if (rocks[rockNum].rockType == "Big") {
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Medium");
            newRock(rocks[rockNum].rock.x,rocks[rockNum].rock.y,"Medium");
        } 
        // remove original rock
        gameObjects.removeChild(rocks[rockNum].rock);
        rocks.splice(rockNum,1);
    }


        public function deleteRocks(){
        gameMode = "delay";
        newRock.gotoAndPlay("bang");

    }



    // MISSILES

    // create a new Missile
    public function newMissile() {
        // create
        var newMissile:Missile = new Missile();

        // set direction
        newMissile.dx = Math.cos(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180);
        newMissile.dy = Math.sin(Math.PI*ship.rotation/180);

        // placement
        newMissile.x = ship.x + newMissile.dx*shipRadius;
        newMissile.y = ship.y + newMissile.dy*shipRadius;

        // add to stage and array
        gameObjects.addChild(newMissile);
        missiles.push(newMissile);
    }

    // animate missiles
    public function moveMissiles(timeDiff:uint) {
        for(var i:int=missiles.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            // move
            missiles[i].x += missiles[i].dx*missileSpeed*timeDiff;
            missiles[i].y += missiles[i].dy*missileSpeed*timeDiff;
            // moved off screen
            if ((missiles[i].x < 0) || (missiles[i].x > 550) || (missiles[i].y < 0) || (missiles[i].y > 400)) {
                gameObjects.removeChild(missiles[i]);
                delete missiles[i];
                missiles.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }

    // remove a missile
    public function missileHit(missileNum:uint) {
        gameObjects.removeChild(missiles[missileNum]);
        missiles.splice(missileNum,1);
    }

    // GAME INTERACTION AND CONTROL

    public function moveGameObjects(event:Event) {
        // get timer difference and animate
        var timePassed:uint = getTimer() - lastTime;
        lastTime += timePassed;
        moveRocks(timePassed);
        if (gameMode != "delay") {
            moveShip(timePassed);
        }
        moveMissiles(timePassed);
        checkCollisions();
    }

    // look for missiles colliding with rocks
    public function checkCollisions() {
        // loop through rocks
        rockloop: for(var j:int=rocks.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
            // loop through missiles
            missileloop: for(var i:int=missiles.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
                // collision detection 
                if (Point.distance(new Point(rocks[j].rock.x,rocks[j].rock.y),
                        new Point(missiles[i].x,missiles[i].y))
                            < rocks[j].rockRadius) {

                    // remove rock and missile
                    rockHit(j);
                    missileHit(i);

                    // add score
                    gameScore += 10;
                    updateScore();

                    // break out of this loop and continue next one
                    continue rockloop;
                }
            }

            // check for rock hitting ship
            if (gameMode == "play") {
                if (shieldOn == false) { // only if shield is off
                    if (Point.distance(new Point(rocks[j].rock.x,rocks[j].rock.y),
                            new Point(ship.x,ship.y))
                                < rocks[j].rockRadius+shipRadius) {

                        // remove ship and rock
                        shipHit();
                        rockHit(j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // all out of rocks, change game mode and trigger more
        if ((rocks.length == 0) && (gameMode == "play")) {
            gameMode = "betweenlevels";
            gameLevel++; // advance a level
            delayTimer = new Timer(2000,1);
            delayTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,nextRockWave);
            delayTimer.start();
        }
    }

    public function endGame() {
        // remove all objects and listeners
        removeChild(gameObjects);
        removeChild(scoreObjects);
        gameObjects = null;
        scoreObjects = null;
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveGameObjects);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpFunction);

        gotoAndStop("gameover");
    }

}
}
```

thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: Can you be more specific instead of just saying "Doesn't Work",  what exact is or is not happening?    Do you have an ENTER_FRAME listener that calls your moveRocks function? All I see is a place where you remove a listener for it.

Comment: I also don't see where you actually delete a rock (eg where you call rockHit)

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code to put everything in... There are 2 issues, 1 is that the rocks don't respond to the boundaries i've tried to put in, they just keep going past the stage. The second is that my deleteRock code doesn't work, I don't think my code is right, i've tried a few ways but have not been successful. However I'm not getting an error for either of these.

Comment: What does `newRock.gotoAndPlay("bang");` do?  Change the graphic?   That's all that you're doing when the rock is out of bounds.  Seems like you should remove them, or reset their position

Comment: That's what i'm trying to get it to do, when it's hit by the missiles. I have an frame on a movie clip called "bang" that I want it to play, this also doesn't work... the movie clip is called Rock_Big but i've tried calling the movie clip too and that didn't seem to work either.. I'm very new to all of this! When they go out of bounds I'd just like them to delete.

Comment: You should be getting errors, looking at your code.  Biggest problem I see is that you have a `newRock` function but many places you are treating it like a MovieClip.   Have your `newRock` method return a reference to the rock that was created, and use a different var name when storing that

Comment: That's why your animation doesn't play,  because `newRock` is a function, not the rock you're treating it like.

Answer (score 0):

first pass out the rock you want to delete

```
  deleteRocks(rocks[i].rock);
```

then remove it from the stage

```
      public function deleteRocks(rock){
         gameMode = "delay";
         trace("Rock Deleted");
        gameObjects.removeChild(rock)  ;        
                 }
```

But I think there is a problem with your if condition that control the removing of rocks. check it out